# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

The query runs perfectly fine when directly executed in database but it gives me above error..I Have gone through similar questions but couldnt find any sol..

My Dao code

```
public String BASshiftingStudentsUpdate(HttpServletRequest request)
        {
            String sql="",msg="";
            String[] checkedApps = request.getParameter("checkedApps") != null&& request.getParameter("checkedApps")!=""?request.getParameter("checkedApps").split("\\,") : null;
            String ac_year=request.getParameter("acyear");              

            try
            {
                if (checkedApps != null)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedApps.length; i++)
                    {                       

                        sql=" insert into pmss_school_students_details(admission_no,student_name,parent_name,native_dist,native_mandal,address,caste_code,subcaste_code,admission_year,"
                            + "admission_dt,admission_class,present_class,student_photo,entered_by,entered_dt,stu_subcaste_new,mobilenumber,parent_proffession,annual_income,date_of_birth,"
                            + "pre_quarterly_marks,pre_annual_marks,achievements,health_problems,height,weight,blood_group,fresh_renewal,identification_marks,orphan,semi_orphan,"
                            + "rescued_child,victim,handycapped,school_code,class_promoted,dept_code,dist_office_code,applied_date,stu_id,status,pre_halfyearly_marks,ac_year,"
                            + "pre_quarterly_marks_max,pre_halfyearly_marks_max,pre_annual_marks_max,gender,boaders,from_school) "

                            + " select admission_no,student_name,parent_name,native_dist,"
                            + "native_mandal,address,caste_code,subcaste_code,admission_year,admission_dt,admission_class,present_class+1  as present_class,student_photo,entered_by,entered_dt,"
                            + "stu_subcaste_new,mobilenumber,parent_proffession,annual_income,date_of_birth,pre_quarterly_marks,pre_annual_marks,achievements,health_problems,"
                            + "height,weight,blood_group,'R' as fresh_renewal,identification_marks,orphan,semi_orphan,rescued_child,victim,handycapped,'"+request.getParameter("to_schools_selected")+"' as school_code,class_promoted,"
                            + "dept_code,dist_office_code,applied_date,(substring(stu_id,1,4))::int+1||substr(stu_id,5) as stu_id,'3' as status,pre_halfyearly_marks,(substring(stu_id,1,4))::int+1||'-'||(substring(stu_id,3,2))::int+2 as ac_year,pre_quarterly_marks_max,"
                            + "pre_halfyearly_marks_max,pre_annual_marks_max,gender,boaders,school_code from pmss_school_students_details "
                            + " where stu_id='"+checkedApps[i]+ "' and school_code='"+  Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("schoolcode").trim())
                            + "' and ac_year=int4(substring('"+ac_year+"',1,4))-1||'-'||int4(substring('"+ac_year+"',6,2))-1";

                        gen.executeUpdate(sql);
                    }

                }
```

executeUpdate Method

```
public int executeUpdate(String sql)
    {
        Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
        SQLQuery  query=null;
        int result=0;
        try
        {
            result=session.createSQLQuery(sql).executeUpdate();

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally
        {
            if (session.isOpen())
            {
                session.close();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The columns in query are same in number.

Comment: You should never append strings that come from the user like that. See here http://bobby-tables.com/ on how and why to use prepared statements. Also the `::type` casting in postgres is legacy. Use `CAST(value AS type)` syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

The colon (`:`) is a prefix for named parameters in Hibernate. Make sure you escape them, e.g. `\:\:int+1`.